# ListAdapter error using @Override

Tags: android

I am getting error in Eclipse Juno with the following code:

```
FilmListAdapter listAdapter = new FilmListAdapter(this, 
        R.layout.film_list_items, data);
listViewInstance.setAdapter(listAdapter);

listViewInstance.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> getView, View view, int i, long l) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
        "click is performed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
        .show();
    }
});
```

When I add the @Override it gives me an error and does not compile. Without it, it compiles, but the click is not working.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the default language in eclipse to Java 1.6.

This can be done by clicking Preferences -> Java -> Compiler and select the compiler compliance level of `1.6`

Comment: It was I fault 

It started to work without @override. I just removed from my listadapter this view.setClickable(true); and it started to work.
Thanks you For good hint))

Comment: Bit of background:  Prior to java 1.6, the @Override decorator was for class methods.  With 1.6 and above, it applies to interfaces as well.